# Passing CDATA in WSO2

Tags: xml, wso2, cdata, wso2-esb

WSO2 4.8.1 has a well-known problem with passing CDATA sections in XML messages. Such sections are always replaced with their contents in the form of XML-escaped string.

Any solution to this problem would be appreciated.

Meanwhile, I have found a page telling about some patch (patch0514) for this purpose:
http://www.yenlo.com/en/how-to-preserve-a-cdata-in-xml-that-is-circulating-in-a-wso2-enterprise-service-bus/

But I have no idea where can I get this patch. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally I found 2 issues there:

1. Configuration of SOAP Builder, that does not preserve CDATA.

I had to change `org.apache.axiom.om.OMXMLBuilderFactory` from Axiom package, to make it using `StAXParserConfiguration.PRESERVE_CDATA_SECTIONS` instead of `StAXParserConfiguration.SOAP`, as follows:

```
public static OMXMLParserWrapper createSOAPModelBuilder(InputStream in, String encoding){
   InputSource is = new InputSource(in);
   is.setEncoding(encoding);
   return  OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory().createSOAPModelBuilder(StAXParserConfiguration.PRESERVE_CDATA_SECTIONS, is);
}
```

2. Incorrect behaviour of XSLT mediator. Even if you have correctly defined CDATA nodes inside your envelope, these will be converted into escaped strings after passing XSLT mediator. I have no solution for XSLT in fact, my choice for now is to avoid using it, because of its numerous problems.