# CData Support in WSo2 Micro Integrator 4.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, cdata, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

In W2O2 Micro Integrator, how do you preserve the following payload? In earlier versions of WSO2, the solution in the following stack overflow discussion worked.  This no longer works in Micro Integrator 4.0.0.

Please refer to the stack overflow discussion: "WSO2 AM 1.9 - Keep CDATA in payload factory".

```
<soapenv:Body>
<![CDATA[
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
    <Test>
        <abc>def</abc>
    </Test>
]]></soapenv:Body>
```

[WSO2 AM 1.9 - Keep CDATA in payload factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590320/wso2-am-1-9-keep-cdata-in-payload-factory)

Answer (score 0):

The steps in the "Keep CData in payload factory" discussion worked after upgrading to  Micro Integrator 4.1.0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).